# diff between tables

Tags: mysql, diff

I have two tables, with the same structure, for example: table "first' with columns 'a','b','c' and table 'second' with the same columns. How to find difference betweet those two tables? 
Of course, I can make some script on python, that will make set(a)-set(b), but I think there is some way to do it in mysql.

UPD:

```
Table 'first'
a   |b   |c
====|====|====
a1  |b1  |c1
a2  |b2  |c2
a3  |b3  |c3

Table 'second'
a   |b   |c
====|====|====
a2  |b2  |c2
a3  |b3  |c3
a4  |b4  |c4
```

the result I need is something like that:

```
Table 'first-second'
a   |b   |c
====|====|====
a1  |b1  |c1
```

Or

```
Table 'second-first'
a   |b   |c
====|====|====
a4  |b4  |c4
```

Comment: mysql doesn't support the set "minus" operator; just set union.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try an outer join. For example, you could find rows present in table `first` but absent in table `second` like this (not tested):

```
SELECT first.a, first.b, first.c FROM first LEFT JOIN second USING(a,b,c) 
WHERE second.a IS NULL
```

The join gives you a table containing all rows present in `first`, like this:

```
first.a first.b first.c second.a second.b second.c
   a1      b1     c1      NULL      NULL     NULL
   a2      b2     c2       a2       b2       c2
```

Now you only have to query for rows with `second.a IS NULL` to find rows absent in `second`.

Performance might be poor since you have to join over all columns.

Answer (score 0):

difference means? differenciate the fields while writing queries ??? u can use `first.a`, `second.a` etc while writing queries.! 
(*hope i answered ur question, if not : throw more light on the question tat i understand it better*)

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where
    table_name = 'FirstTable'
    and table_schema = 'DatabaseHoldingFirstTable'
    and column_name not in (
        select column_name
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name = 'SecondTable'
        and table_schema = 'DatabaseHoldingSecondTable'
    );
```